# How to make morethan 6 concurrent rest API calls

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, http

My requirement is to make 20 rest API calls on click of a button. When I inspect, I can see chrome only allows max 6 concurrent calls and put other APIs in a stack. I'm using $.ajax to make API calls. How can I overwrite the default limit of any browser?

Comment: You can't, that's a hard limit from the browser. If this was unlimited you could use browsers to perform DDoS attacks, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. The browser sets the limit. There is no API to attempt to change that limit. You can start as many calls as you like, but the browser will only process as many as it allows. This is largely transparent to your code, other than (of course) that you won't see a completion of one of the calls that queued until after at least one of the earlier ones has completed.

Note that the limit is typically different for different devices. I haven't checked it lately, but it used to be 6-8 for most desktop browsers but only 2 for the "same" browser on mobile.

Comment: Few answers on StackOverflow like, HTTP/2.0 doesn't set any limit where HTTP/1 has a specific limit. is this make sense?

Comment: @AbbasAli - It's not about the version of HTTP. HTTP/2 allows multiplexing on a single connection, so may help if you're making these 20 request to the same endpoint, but again, it's the browser that sets the limit on concurrent requests.

Answer (score 1):

So should probably apply some form of orchestration. Create your own api/service that performs all the API calls that you want performed with one click of a button. Then have the button click call your own 'Proxy' API.